# access a POSIX function using dlopen

Tags: c, shared-libraries, posix, dlopen, dlsym

POSIX 2008 introduces several file system functions, which rely on directory descriptor when determining a path to the file (I'm speaking about `-at` functions, such as `openat`, `renameat`, `symlinkat`, etc.). I doubt if all POSIX platforms support it (well, at least the most recent versions seem to support) and I'm looking for a way to determine if platform supports such functions. Of course one may use `autoconf` and friends for compile-time determination, but I'm looking for a possibility to find out whether implementation supports `-at` functions *dynamically*.

The first that comes to my mind is a `dlopen()`/`dlsym()`/`dlclose()` combo; at least I've successfully loaded the necessary symbols from `/usr/libc.so.6` shared library. However, libc may be (or *is*?) named differently on various platforms. Is there a list of standard locations to find libc? At least on Linux `/lib/libc.so` appears to be not a symbolic link to shared library, but a `ld` script. May be there exist some other way to examine *during runtime* if a POSIX function is supported? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE 1
#include <dlfcn.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main ()
{
    void * funcaddr = dlsym(RTLD_DEFAULT, "symlinkat");
    /* -----------------------^ magic! */
    printf ("funcaddr = %p\n", funcaddr);
}
```

Output:

```
funcaddr = 0x7fb62e44c2c0
```

Magic explanation: your program is already linked with libc, no need to load it again.

Note, this is actually GNU libc feature, as hinted by _GNU_SOURCE. POSIX reserves RTLD_DEFAULT "for future use", and then proceeds to define it exactly like GNU libc does. So strictly speaking it is not guaranteed to work on all POSIX systems.

Comment: Heck, I thought that answer would be simple but could not even imagine that it will be such simple! Now I've realized that even Windows has `GetModuleHandleW(NULL)`, which provides the same thing. Thank you very much!

Comment: P.S. I couldn't manage to get it work with either C4Droid or CCTools on Android. Since Android is partially POSIX-compatible, I guess that such behaviour may be a bug or an unimplemented feature.

Comment: Oops, you've changed NULL to RTLD_DEFAULT. Everything works now. Thank you very much!

Comment: This is actually GNU libc feature, as hinted by `_GNU_SOURCE`. POSIX reserves `RTLD_DEFAULT` "for future use", so strictly speaking it is not guaranteed to work on all POSIX systems.